# Происхождение слова "положение"

Tags: этимология

Происхождение слова "положение", заимствованное оно или нет?

Answer (score 3):

> Происхождение слова "положение"...

См. http://etymological.academic.ru/3851 :

> **положение**
>
> Семантическая калька XVIII в. франц. *position.*
>
> *Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.*

Answer (score 0):

Слово "положение" действительно является семантической калькой и относится к заимствованным словам.

Семантическая калька - интересное явление в линвистике. В этом случае из другого языка заимствуется не само слово, а его значение, причем значение переносное.

"Положить" - исконное (общеславянское) слово, как и многие слова, обозначающие действия. Словообразование в русском языке: положить - положение. Так обычно образуются существительные, называющее действие, но в нашем случае это многозначное слово со следующими значениями:  расположение в пространстве,  постановка тела или его частей др.

Вот это переносное значение и было заимствовано в Петровскую эпоху из фр. языка через польское посредство от лат positio (позиция),  от  ponere (класть, располагать, ставить).